# Animations won't start from the beginning when calling gotoAndPlay -- Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frame

I have animations in my second frame ( a falling bird and moving pipes ), once i jump to the third frame i give the user the choice to restart the game by doing gotoAndPlay(1) on a button click, the problem is once i go back the the second frame, the animations continue on playing and not starting from the beginning, i want to restart all the frame animations from their initial positions, what i did is the give every object on the stage the starting (X,Y) coordinates in the script, but it gets difficult when i have so many objects, is there a better way of using this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first: if you're making a game, you probably shouldn't be performing any mission-critical logic on the timeline itself. Look into OOP tutorials.

That being said, what you're looking for is a recursive `gotoAndPlay`, meaning that you want all the children of the stage and all of their children (etc) to play from the first frame:

```
function recursiveGotoAndPlay(clip:DisplayObjectContainer, frame:int):void 
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < clip.numChildren; i++)
    {
        var child:DisplayObject = clip.getChildAt(i);
        if(child is DisplayObjectContainer)
        {
            recursiveGotoAndPlay(child as DisplayObjectContainer, frame);
        }
    }
    if(clip is MovieClip)
    {
        MovieClip(clip).gotoAndPlay(frame);
    }
}
```

Instead of calling the native `gotoAndPlay(1)`, you will call `recursiveGotoAndPlay(stage, 1)`.

Comment: Please note that it is customary to mark an answer as correct if it answers your question.